# Solr facet division of 2 aggregation function

Tags: solr, aggregation, facet

I'm storing 2 type of data for each record in my Solr core. first one is the total number of tasks in each day `(total)`  and the second one is the total number of **finished** tasks in each day (`finished`). I want to compute how many percents of tasks was finished in each **month** using solr json facet query. Something like this:

```
{
  finishedRate : {
    type : range,
    field : date,
    gap : "+1MONTH"
    facet: "div(sum(finished),sum(total))"
  }
}
```

but it said

> org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Unknown aggregation 
>   agg_div

I test the following query to solve SyntaxError, but it gives me the maximum percentage of tasks that finished in a day for each month:

```
{
  finishedRate : {
    type : range,
    field : date,
    gap : "+1MONTH"
    facet: "max(div(sum(finished),sum(total)))"
  }
}
```

how can I implement this query?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar use case a while back. After searching through the official Solr documentation, I finally gave up the idea of dividing it in the query itself.

I took another approach of just calculating the two values in the Solr query and then handling the division in my code.

Something like this -

```
{
  finishedRate : {
    type : range,
    field : date,
    gap : "+1MONTH",
    facet : {
      "finished tasks" : sum(finished),
      "total tasks" : sum(total)
    }
  }
}
```